# How to share Android Studio modules between projects with Git

Tags: java, android, git, svn, android-studio

Until now I was using Eclipse + SVN with the typical project App + project libraries.

I use a single SVN repository using the following structure:

```
root
 -Apps
    -App1
      -trunk
      -tags
      -branches
 -Libs
    -Lib1
      -trunk
      -tags
      -branches
    -Lib2
      -trunk
      -tags
      -branches
```

I ported the project to Android Studio and I'm trying to do store the modules in a  Git repo. I'm starting with Git and I don't achieve it, it seems like git is prepared to have one project per repository, isn't it? How can I solve that?

Thanks

Comment: This link can be very useful for what you are trying to achieve : https://gitsubmoduleasandroidtudiomodule.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git is ready for that, just use git submodules. Separate your projects in different repositories and then link them together as submodules, let me point you to a guide:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

So for example, if you are in your project A and want to add project B, do:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/myrepo/B
```

And then do:

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so there is no way of handling all the modules in the same repository right?

Comment: No, but submodules works pretty neat, based on personal experience

Comment: sound easy but in practice is not so when you have project with few libraries in Eclipse which are already submodules in git and configured in Eclipse. During import of such a Eclipse project to Android Studio all kind of things are happenening